# Replace Approve text from button with SF symbol in {{ application['ApplicationDecision'].approve(class_="btn btn-primary")}}

Tags: css, python-3.x, flask

```
{{ application['ApplicationDecision'].approve(class_="btn btn-primary")}}
```

In Forms:

```
approve = SubmitField(u'Approve')
```

I tried to replace the approve text with the SF symbol:

Within Forms->

```
 approve = SubmitField('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>')
```

In Review page:

```
{{ application['ApplicationDecision'].approve(class_="btn btn-primary")}}
```